# Aligning a span to fall underneath an input box

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor-server-side

I have the code below for a blazor component which displays a textbox that can be edited with the click
of a button.

```
                @if (_editing)
                {
                    <div class="floatingbox position-relative">
                        <input type="text" value="@AddText" @oninput="@(e => { AddText = e.Value.ToString(); })" 
                        @onblur="@(e => { InputBlured(e); })" @onkeyup="@(e => KeyPressed(e))" maxlength="75" />
                        <button type="button" class="button_search_term">
                            <div @onclick="ProcessInput"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="floatingbox position-relative" @ondblclick="ToggleMode">
                        <span>@AddText</span>
                    </div>
                }
```

I want to display this span right under the  input box for error messages

```
            <span hidden="@IsShow" class="error-color">Error message</span>
```

I wrote this css and used display block but what happens is everytime there is an error
the span above is enabled and rearranges the input box controls underneath one another. There can be many of these controls
on a page.

```
            .error-color{
                color:red;
                //display:block;
                padding-left:35px;
            }
```

How can I style this such that the span stays directly under the inputbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `position:absolute`

See this example:

```css
.control{
  position: relative;
}
.error{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="control">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">ERROR</span>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that you have to put `position:relative` to the parent Element.

Your final HTML shoudl look something like this:

```
<div class="floatingbox position-relative">
  <input type="text" value="@AddText" @oninput="@(e => { AddText = e.Value.ToString(); })" @onblur="@(e => { InputBlured(e); })" @onkeyup="@(e => KeyPressed(e))" maxlength="75" />
  <button type="button" class="button_search_term">
    <div @onclick="ProcessInput"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
  </button>
  <!-- insert your error span here -->
  <span hidden="@IsShow" class="error-color">Error message</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I put the span and which parent are you referring to?

Comment: Do you have just one span for the whole site or just one per input element?
I updated my answer with a working example.

Comment: I use span all over the application.